# LineageOS: Phone and Contacts crash

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, lineageos

I've switched from Cyanogenmod to LineageOS using the experimental build and then flashing a nightly build afterwards. This worked great except for the fact that the phone and contacts app kept on crashing. I reflashed the nightly and -- to be sure -- this time I flashed the GApps immediately after as well.

I've tried both the Gapps "stock" package and the "micro", because I thought the problem could lie within Hangouts. It didn't.

When I boot my phone up, I get `android.process.acore has stopped working` (or something along the lines of that; I'm using the German translation) and this message get's repeated everytime I try to open the phone, messages or contacts. All other apps seem to work fine.

Interestingly enough, I can *get* called. The aforementioned error message is displayed, however, I can tap on `Kill app` without killing the conversation.

Comment: "I reflashed the nightly and -- to be sure -- this time I flashed the GApps immediately after as well." - this only applies to fresh installs. For anything older that doesn't have GAPPS before... back up and do a fresh one.

Comment: What's the android version in cyanogenmod, and on lineage? phone and contacts are system apps,  may be you were in different android versions.

Comment: @AndyYan I reflashed the nightly w/o gapps and manually downloaded the Google Phone app, sadly w/o any success. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: @RahulGopi Damn, that actually could be the problem. I was on one of the latest CM 13 nightlies for my LGG3 and didn't reliase that Lineage was already on Android 7.1. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: @theCed7 A matching version of GAPPS, I guess?

Comment: @AndyYan I've flashed the 7.1 GApps version; shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `cynogenmod zip` file somewhere stored then I think it is very easy to restore it. Just `extract` the `cynogenmod` on your computer and go to system->apps and copy the apks which are not working (eg.`Phone`, `Contact` in your case). Now also extract the `nightly build` which is giving you errors and go to system->apps and find the `phone.apk` and `contacts.apk` and delete it. Now just paste those `apks` which you had copied from `CynogenMod` and compress the modified `Lineage OS` in `zip` format. Now you are all done. Flash the newly created `zip` file and comment here if it worked (which is going to work in most case).